# Automatically copy/sync updated directory to another folder in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, sync

So I have a Git repo on my local (Windows 8) drive and within it are several projects, each with their own sub-dir. I want to setup something such that as I update/save files within this one particular project, this process maintains a synced copy in another location/directory. If this was Linux I'm sure this would be easily doable with a cronjob, but I have no clue how to do something like this in Windows 8. How do I maintain an auto-synced copy?

Comment: Would a junction point/symbolic link work for you?

Comment: I think, yes, that should work

Comment: Basically you don't really copy anything that way, but just access the target folder from a different path. For example you could use the following command: `mklink /j "C:\another\folder" "C:\repo\folder"` (the syntax is `mklink /j "<junction point>" "<target folder>"`; quotes are required to avoid issues with space characters; junction points are only supported on local NTFS drives).

Comment: Sweet thanks, it worked. Post that code as an answer so I can properly attribute and give you points.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/562160/backup-but-leave-old-versions-of-files-on-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Possible solution

Use junction points/symbolic links: nothing gets actually copied, and you just access the target folder from a different path. For example you could use the following command:

```
mklink /j "C:\another\folder" "C:\repo\folder"
```

The syntax is:

```
mklink /j "<junction point>" "<target folder>"
```

Quotes are required to avoid issues with space characters.

### Known limitations

- [Junction points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point) and symbolic links are only supported on NTFS.
- You can't create junction points targeting remote shares. In such cases you have to create a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) instead. Symbolic links were introduced with Windows Vista, but are also available in Windows XP through third-party filter drivers. For Vista and later, the syntax is the following:

  ```
  mklink /d "symbolic link" "X:\path\to\target\folder"
  ```

  **Note** Per default system settings, only users in the Administrators group can create symbolic links.

Answer (score 0):

Try [SyncToy](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=15155&ei=K-35UtTRCoWYrAfy6oDgBw&usg=AFQjCNHIZAFL5XkV6srYbMvaYau6X5yYaw). The only problem is that this cannot be scheduled.
But perfectly does sync the files over multiple locations.